# How can I add a message to a topic to a message by using the API?

Tags: javascript, events, bots, circuit, circuit-sdk

We have a bot who is connected via node-sdk (https://www.npmjs.com/package/circuit-sdk) with Circuit. We use the following code

```
this.addEventListeners = function addEventListeners(client) {
    client.addEventListener('itemAdded', function (evt) {
            client.addTextItem(evt.item.convId, 'answer from bot');
    });
};
```

but then, the message is not shown under the current topic but as a separate message in the conversation.

Let me explain it with a screenshot:

Screenshot from circuit ui with example dialog

[image]

If I open a new topic (`"Topic"` in my screenshot) with a message (`"Hi, this is the first message"`), the bot opens a new topic aswell in which it replies to my message (`"Answer from Bot (via Websocket)"`). How to get it to reply in the topic I opened?

Comment: Hi @JoHo please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add some more code in you question, that can help us understand your problem.

Comment: Hi @BlizZard I updated my description, perhaps you can help me now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the id for the thread (parentId) in the addTextItem API. See https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_addTextItem.

E.g.

```
client.addEventListener('itemAdded', function (evt) {
    client.addTextItem(evt.item.convId, {
        content: 'answer from bot',
        parentId: evt.item.itemId
    });
});
```